# Why do Opacity and Size selectors in Krita get disabled all the time?

Tags: krita

The Opacity and Size selectors in the top menu of Krita get disabled ever so often. I have not managed to re-enable them during the same session. If I open a new file, they are enabled again. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Holding shift and dragging the pointer still works to change size, but the selectors remain disabled.

[image: Top menu selectors]

Krita 3.0.94, OS X El Capitan 10.11.5.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. Unfortunately I'm going to do the very un-welcoming thing of migrating your question... fixing software behavior is best served by Super User. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Those parameters are for the brush tool and drawing tools. You should have those tools activated when you have a document open. These options are disabled by default if there is no document open. So either the tools are not activated or there is no document open.

Comment: These clarifying questions should probably be a comment bro

Comment: @PsychoData I agree that the part of the answer was a question. I have edited the answer so that it states the reason for the opacity sliders being inactive , which is the answer for the question unless it is a bug.